# How can I save the configuration value in a custom submit form method

Tags: forms, 8

I've been wondering if it was possible to use the configuration system instead of playing directly with the database. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['action'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#submit' => [[$this, 'myMethod']],
        '#value' => $this->t('Test')
    );
    return $form;
}

public function myMethod($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->setConfigurationValue('my_config', 'my test value!');
    $this->saveConfiguration(); // <---- Is that 'kind of' possible?
}
```

So, I was wondering if it was possible to get the real "config class" by some way and call `$config->save()`. I started to look at the source and I think it's probably possible using the configuration engine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blockForm is used to configure a block. The configuration is then used to build the block.

If you want to use the configuration system to store data in the database use one of these methods:

1. [Simple Configuration Form](https://www.drupal.org/node/2206607)
2. [Creating a configuration entity
   type](https://www.drupal.org/node/1809494)

Comment: What I was looking was more something like that:
``$config =\Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('module.whatever');``. With how to generate the name. But if not possible, I'll use your method.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what a simple configuration form does.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the routing information at the bottom. That should do it.